# How do I send html email with work items delivered from last build in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to automate the release workflow by using VSTS pipelines, the component which i need to deliver is basically a library.

The VSTS pipeline is now building the Visual Studio solution and generating the binary files in the artifacts folder, but i need to send an email to the QA team with the list of work items which have been delivered as part of the release.

I have found a VSTS task in the marketplace which generates the release notes using MD files:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-GenerateReleaseNotes-Task&targetId=b4f49e36-84e5-48a6-b338-51f8ecc1d8d7

However, what I need is a task based on a customizable HTML template and send in the attachments a ZIP file with the content of the artifacts folder.

Anyone know how could i implement this behaviour as part of the pipeline?

Comment: The extension above supports also HTML format.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I send html email with work items delivered from last build in VSTS?

In fact, you have already found the answer, just need to go one step further.

In the Usage and Description of Types of Template about that extension, you could get the following instructions:

> but it also possible to generate other formats such as **HTML with
>   appropriate templates**.
>
> The use of a template allows the user to define the layout and fields
>   shown in the release notes document. It is basically a markdown file
>   (or **other format of your choice**)

So, this extension should supports HTML format.

As test, I add that task with html template file `build-basic-template.htm`:

[image]

Note: Set the Output file with `.htm` format and [template here](https://github.com/rfennell/AzurePipelines/tree/master/SampleTemplates/GenerateReleaseNotes%20(Original%20Powershell%20based)) (I use the first one).

Besides, if you want to seed email with this `.htm` file, you could use the [Build Notification](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-EASBuild.BuildNotification) task or [Send email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) task.

Hope this helps.